# INSERT command for auto increment field in access from asp.net website

Tags: c#, sql, asp-classic

I've got my primary key set to auto increment in my access database.

How do I specify that I want the primary key to have the next available value?

**e.g.**

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Table VALUES (?,"string","string");", conn);
```

thanks!

Comment: You don't, that's why it's called "auto increment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table as such:

Table

```
 ID    SomeString     SomeString2
```

where ID is the primary key, then you'd not need to specify the value for the primary key. It would be "auto-incremented" as you have specified that.

So you'd enter:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Table (SomeString, SomeString2) VALUES ('stringA','stringB')", conn);
```

**Note**: *Its a good practice to always mention the column names when performing insertion of records.*

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

If it is set to auto increment you dont have to specify a value for it

just do

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Table VALUES ("string","string");", conn);
```

although one would prefer you write the column names explicitly

Answer (score 0):

If the database field is already set to auto-incremente, then you don't need to worry about it!

Just insert the other fields!
INSERT into Table VALUES ("string","string")

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip it:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Table VALUES ("string","string");", conn);
```